# code igniter :: $_GET?

Tags: php, codeigniter, get

In my projects i often use get params as a temporary way to test things with different values.

However it seems like you cannot access get params in code igniter?

I am aware I could build a param into my functions and pass the value as a url segment.

But i dont want to be doing that every time I wish to test something.

So,

is there any way to use get values in CI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` and set it as `$_GET`:

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_GET);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enable query strings in your config file. Find this.

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```

and change it to true.

Comment: Is this the only way? as I really dont want to enable them just for testing as it will break all links ect

Comment: I am guessing here, but I think setting $this->config->set_item('enable_query_strings', TRUE); in your controller, would allow you to accept query string for testing in that controller.